# Sitecore Droplink set property not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6, glass-mapper

I have created the Glassmapper Models for all the items, I have a droplink in one of my Sitecore item.
The Following is the model for the item with droplink field.

```
    [SitecoreClass]
   public class Field:BaseItem
    {
        [SitecoreField("Mapper Item")]
        public virtual LinkedItem MapperItem { get; set; }                
    }
```

Mapper Item field is a droplink field in sitecore,
`BaseItem` class has all the sitecore base properties like:

```
        [SitecoreId]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Name)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.DisplayName)]
    public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Url)]
    public virtual string Url { get; set; }

    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Path)]
    public virtual string Path { get; set; }

    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.ContentPath)]
    public virtual string ContentPath { get; set; }

    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.TemplateId)]
    public virtual Guid TemplateId { get; set; }

    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.TemplateName)]
    public virtual string TemplatedName { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField("__created")]
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField("__updated")]
    public virtual DateTime Updated { get; set; }
```

and `LinkedItem` has the following properties:

```
[SitecoreClass]
public class LinkedItem:BaseItem
{
    [SitecoreField("Field ID")]
    public virtual string FieldID { get; set; }
    [SitecoreField("Display Name")]
    public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }
    [SitecoreField("Field Type")]
    public virtual string FieldType { get; set; }
}
```

I get the `LinkedItem` object in the `MapperItem` property when I am accessing the `Field` object, But if i try to set the `MapperItem` property its not saving it in the corresponding field ("Mapper Item" field), but I don't get any error.

I'm using the following code to set the droplink

```
fieldItem.MapperItem = ItemUtility.GetItem<LinkedItem>(new Guid("some valid guid available in the droplist source"));
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Are you following instructions here http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial11 ? Also you need to set "SitecoreType" attribute on your LinkedItem class, something like
 [SitecoreType(TemplateId = "GUID HERE", AutoMap = true)]

Comment: @AhmedOkour: But SitecoreType is not available, SitecoreClass is the available attribute.

Comment: Did you add this namespace? using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.Attributes ?

Comment: Added Glass.Sitecore.Mapper.Configuration.Attributes, Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.Attributes is not available.

Comment: What glass mapper version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your on an old version of Glass mapper? Try adding the template reference like so:

```
[SitecoreClass(TemplateId = "{5281CBCF-1A2D-413A-B182-2854FC6B9176}")]
```

In the newest version it should be set as follows:

- The namespace should be: using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.Attributes;
- The classes should have an attribute: [SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]

This link contains a good screen shot of the correct implmentation fo the above: http://www.glass.lu/en/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial11.aspx

Things to Check:

- Is the correct nuget package installed/are you able to install the latest?: http://www.glass.lu/en/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial1.aspx
- Is the field name "Mapper Item" unique? If not Sitecore/Glass will pick the first found not always the right one.